# Solve $z^{1+i}=4$

Tags: complex-numbers, multivalued-functions

$\def\Log{\operatorname{Log}}$
I have to solve $z^{1+i}=4$. Is there any easy way?

I'm starting like this:

$$e^{(1+i)\Log z}=e^{2\Log2}$$

Then I solve

$$(1+i)\Log z=2\Log2$$

But I really doubt I can do that like this, since $\Log$ is multivalued...

Edit:

$$(1+i)(\ln|z|+i\arg z+i2k\pi)=2(\ln|2|+i2n\pi), k,n\in\mathbb{Z}$$

Comment: What is the definition of $\log(z)$? there are two one using the principle value and the other that encompasses all values.

Comment: the one I use is that second one, since I have to find all $z$ satisying this equation.

Comment: Then why are you worried about multivaluedness then?

Comment: This is certainly the right method, just take account of the many-valuedness.

Comment: So you need to find _all_ $z$ such that _one of_ the values of $z^{1+i}$ equals $4$?

Comment: I edited first post, is that ok? How can I take it further?

Comment: Yes, Tony. Exactly that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the definition $\Log z = \ln |z|+i\arg z$.
$$e^{(1+i)\Log z}=e^{(1+i)\ln |z|+(1+i)i\,\arg z}=e^{\ln|z|-\arg z}\cdot e^{i(\ln |z|+\arg z)}=4$$
Taking the log-maginitude and argument of the above equation,
$$
\ln|z|-\arg z = \ln 4
$$
$$
\ln|z|+\arg z = 2\pi k
$$
Solving this system gives you a value of $z$ for each integer $k$.